# Copy workbooks from the link addresses and paste it in to the range address

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am trying to write the code which will copy the content of specific sheet  from another workbook based on the link address in my main workbook. Then, it should paste it to the sheet range in my main workbook that is also provided as range address. This has to be performed in the loop as I want to repeat it for 2 other workbooks stored under different links. All of those 3 workbooks stored under different links have the sheet named 'Data' which must be pasted in my main workbook.

Here is my main workbook that I have always opened when executing this code. In the sheet 'Start' I have the table that specifies 1) Link to the workbook from where data should be copied (col A), 2) Sheet Range Address where the data should be pasted in this main workbook (col B).

[image]

In my code, all would work except for the fact that the content of all 3 workbooks from provided links are pasted into 'Sheet1'!A1. I tried to F8 the code and it looks like the code does not loop properly in the column B.

```
Sub Copy_Paste()

Dim Ws_MainWS As Worksheet
Dim intFirstRow_Ws2 As Integer
Dim intLastCol_Ws2 As Integer
Dim ActiveWs As Variant
Dim Var_Ws2Link As Variant
Dim intListRow As Integer
Dim intListRow_Paste As Integer
Dim objTable As Excel.ListObject
Dim objRange As Excel.Range
Dim intLastRow_Ws1Tbl As Integer

Set Ws_MainWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Start")
Set ActiveWs = ActiveWorkbook
Set objTable = Ws_MainWS.ListObjects("tblStart")

intLastRow_Ws1Tbl = Ws_MainWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
intFirstRow_Ws2 = 1
Const ColumnStart As Integer = 1

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'Copy and Paste into provided sheet range address
    'Loop through Links to other workbooks
    For intListRow = 3 To intLastRow_Ws1Tbl
        Set Var_Ws2Link = Ws_MainWS.Cells(intListRow, 1)

            With objTable
                'Loop through pasting range addresses and paste
                For intListRow_Paste = 1 To .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
                    Set objRange = Excel.Range(.DataBodyRange(intListRow_Paste, .ListColumns("Sheet Range address").Index).Value)
                         Workbooks.Open Var_Ws2Link, local:=True
                         intLastCol_Ws2 = Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                        With Worksheets("Data")
                            .Range(.Cells(intFirstRow_Ws2, ColumnStart), .Cells(.Rows.Count, intLastCol_Ws2)).Copy
                            objRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                            Application.CutCopyMode = False
                            Set objRange = Nothing
                            ActiveWorkbook.Close
                        End With

                    Exit For

                Next intListRow_Paste
            End With

            Set objTable = Nothing

    Next intListRow

MsgBox "Done"


Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:

Set objTable = Nothing

End Sub
```

For looping through Pasting range addresses, I use object table.
I would be grateful for any help on that!

Comment: Why do you have `Exit For` in the middle of your loop? I don't think I follow why you have both the `intListRow` loop and `intListRow_Paste` loop.

Comment: I have Exit For, because the loop did not have end ( I can imagine it is not correct). I also have 2 loops because the one with intListRow_Paste is for looping in the table and I couldn't make it work with the first one intListRow.

Comment: The other thing I found is that I can only use the link to other workbooks in col A of the table as Variant in order to open them and copy the content, while for range addresses in column B of the table I have to use as Excel.Range in order for code to treat them as the address reference and paste in Sheet1 or 2 or 3.

Comment: You need one loop, you loop through each row in the table, open the workbook in the first column and paste the contents to the cell in the second column. Can you work with that?

Comment: I tried with one loop. But the problem is that first column (the links to other workbooks) are defined as variant and the second column ( the range addresses to paste the contents) are defined as Excel range. Therefore, I cannot make this one loop work because I would need either change first column to Excel.Range - this does not work as other Workbooks do not open, or I would need to change second column to variant - this also does not work for pasting after. So, I have no clue how to continue :(

Comment: Don't really understand that. Define a range variable to loop through the table (or a Long) and then reference the value.

Comment: Ah perhaps the problem is the format of the addresses `sheet1!a1` - do they have to be like that?

Comment: If yes, you could use `split` on the ! to split the address into sheet and range and reference each element separately.

Comment: I am not really sure how to use split in here. I only know that using Excel.Range for addresses like 'sheet1a1' works in the loop to paste. So in the best scenario, I could loop through the table using Excel.range. The only thing is that I cannot loop through the first column (links to workbooks) as they are defined as variants. I have tried to define them as Excel. Ranges so that they are part of the table but then the links to workbooks do not open and nothing is copied from them.

Comment: I'll post some code in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have a two-column table like yours, this works for me.

`Split` splits your address into two, the bit before the ! (sheet) and the bit after (cell address) so will crash if the address if not of this form.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range, t As ListObject, wb As Workbook, v As Variant

Set t = Worksheets(1).ListObjects("Table1")

For Each r In t.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange 'loop through column 1
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(r.Value)         'open workbook
    v = Split(r.Offset(, 1).Value, "!")      'split cell in 2nd column
    wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(replace(v(0),"'","")).Range(v(1))        'paste
    wb.Close False
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. Unfortunately, The Pasting does not work. I get error 9 Subscript out of range.

Comment: v(0) = "Sheet1" and v(1) = "A1"

Comment: Have you adjusted your sheet references etc if necessary? Are you pasting to the workbook containing the code? Does it work at all? Have you stepped through?

Comment: Yes I did all the adjustments. I can see it has the problem with reading through v(0) and v(1) . In column B of main workbook range address is written to the cell like that: ''Sheet1'!A1  . With that v(0) reads "'Sheet1'" and v(1) reads "A1"  . As you can see that it reads Sheet1 with apostrops before it is in the quotation marks. I tried changing how range address 'Sheet1'!A1 is written to the cell but nothing works

Comment: My mistake, I hadn't spotted the apostrophes. I've made a change above, can you try it again?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)